# Print random integer and phrase in same line?

Tags: python

Not sure if this is asked before but: How do you print "searching for x" where "x" is a random integer? I have my code below:

```
from random import randint

numbers = []
random = randint(1,50)

for i in range(0,10):
  numbers.append(randint(1,50))

for j in range(len(numbers)):
  print('searching for')
  print(random)
  print('in')
  print(numbers)
  break
```

And [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PUKFs.png) is what happens but I want "searching for __ in [list]" on the same line. Is there a way to do it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Aside from the linked duplicates, what happened when you typed `python print on same line` into a search engine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
print(f'searching for {random} in {numbers}')
```

it requires python 3.6 or up and it is called an f-string

Answer (score 0):

```py
for n in numbers:
  print("Searching for {} in {}".format(n, numbers))
```

Does that answer what you want to do?